# C# WPF: Как открыть окно поверх всех окон так, чтобы оно не сворачивало полноэкранные приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf

В Windows при переключении языка с помощью <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> *(не наоборот)* поверх всех окон появляется окно с отображением выбранного языка.

[image]

---

**В WPF-приложении понадобилось реализовать такое же окно:**

Я реализовал окно со свойством `Topmost=true`, чтобы оно всегда было поверх всех окон. Но есть проблема — при открытии этого окна оно сворачивает все полноэкранные приложения. То есть, если я открою его в любой полноэкранной игре, то окно игры свернется. В то же время с окном переключения раскладки Windows этого не происходит.

Насколько я понимаю, в Windows используется не окно, а что-то вроде оверлея, типа Discord. Но Discord ищет запущенную игру, в то время как окно Windows может быть нарисовано поверх любых окон.

**Как я могу реализовать такое же окно? Желательно без использования библиотек DirectX, чтобы этот оверлей работал не только для конкретных окон**

Comment: Когда я раньше писал читы для игр, то пользовался отрисовкой каких-либо сущностей с помощью directX. Можете попробовать загуглить "DirectX Overlay"

Comment: Нашёл вот такую статейку - https://guidedhacking.com/threads/c-direct-x-overlay-with-setup.15295/. Думаю, она поможет прояснить эту тему

Comment: В WinForms достаточно задавать значение `TopMost = true;` в таймере. Такое окно будет поверх всех и не будет мешать полноэкранным приложениям. Но для реакции на `Esc` нужен хук, скорее всего.

Comment: думаю в игре это происходит из-за того что игры настраивают дисплеи под себя, поэтому и выбрасывает из них, комментарий @Frehzy мне кажется подходящим

Comment: [Toast notifications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне кажется, уведомления — это не совсем то, что мне нужно, потому что их форму и положение нельзя изменять как захочется. И, вроде бы, они не будут отображаться поверх всех окон

Comment: `TopMost` пробовали задавать? В WPF это тоже должно работать. Только не надо при этом активировать окно (задавать ему фокус) - это свернёт полноэкранное приложение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так вот в чем ошибка была) У окна итак установлено свойство `Topmost`, но я его при этом активировал постоянно. Теперь все как надо, спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку оверлей DirectX должен отрисовываться для конкретного окна, а мне нужна реализация этого окошка поверх вообще всех окон, я решил отказаться от идеи отрисовки оверлея.

По сути решение оказалось на поверхности. Нашел его по подсказке [`Alexander Petrov`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov).

Первое, что нужно сделать — это задать окну свойство `Topmost="True"`, чтобы окно всегда было поверх остальных окон. А также `ShowInTaskbar="False"`, чтобы окно не сворачивало полноэкранные приложения появляясь на панели задач при открытии.

При этом ни в коем случае нельзя активировать его, то есть вызывать `Focus()` и `Activate()`, чтобы окно не перехватывало фокус у других окон.

В целом это работает, но если случайно нажать на окно мышью — оно все равно получит фокус. Чтобы избежать этого, можно переопределить метод `OnSourceInitialized()` и запретить окну получать фокус. Решение нашел [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628353/14519908).

```cs
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    SetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
        GetWindowLong(helper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
}   

private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

---

*В первоначальной версии вопроса я также отметил, что окну **нужен** фокус, чтобы срабатывало событие `KeyDown` для отслеживания нажатия некоторых клавиш. С отключением фокуса окна событие `KeyDown` использовать не получится. Вместо этого можно использовать глобальные горячие клавиши, через пакет `NHotkey.Wpf` (можно установить через `NuGet`)*

Comment: У `UIElement` - есть свойство `Focusable` через которое можно также отказаться от фокуса на окне (или любом другом `UIElement`), без использования маршалинга...

Comment: `Focusable`, к сожалению, не работает так как нужно. При нажатии на окно курсором оно все равно перехватывает фокус